# Indicator alongside first occurence

Tags: key, unique, uniqueidentifier, indicator

I new to SQL and working in Management studio 2008. I would appreciate any insight you would have with the below:

Essentially I would like to place a new column, which places a "1" if that's the first time that the contents of Columns A and Column D occur and a "0" at every other occurence. I could also just create a column (column E) which concatenates column A and D and then a column F which puts a "1" at the first occurence of each value in column E and a 0 at every subsequent occurence of that value.

Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you please add some sample data to your question, along with what you'd expect in your extra column? It's difficult to understand the issue from what you've written